# TCP/IP - Solving the C10K with the thread per client approach

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, tcp, c10k

After reading the famous [C10k article](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html#aio%22C10K%20article%22) and searching on the web about how things have evolved since it was written, I would like to know if it would be possible for a today's standard server to handle **>10000 concurrent** connections using **a thread per connection** (possibly with the help of a pool of threads to avoid the creation/killing process).

---

**Some details that may affect the approach to the problem:**

1. Input, intermediate processing and output.
2. Length of each connection.
3. Technical specifications of the server (cores, processors, RAM, etc...)
4. Combining this system with alternative techniques like AIO, polling, green threads, etc...

---

Obviously I'm not an expert in the matter, so any remarks or advices will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Very briefly: while it is possible, it is rarely a good idea (with thread switching cost reaching 100K CPU cycles easily, having too many threads gets expensive for no apparent reason).

Answer (score 73):

Absolutely. A standard server can handle more than **10K concurrent connections** using the model with **one thread per connection**. I have build such an application, and five years ago, it was running with more than 50K concurrent connections per process on a standard Linux server. Nowadays, it should be possible to run the same application with more than 250K concurrent connections on current hardware.

There are only a few things to keep in mind:

- Reuse threads by using a thread pool. There is no need to kill threads if they are not used, because the resource usage should be optimized for peak loads.
- Stack size: By default each Linux thread reserves 8 MB for its stack. That sums up to 80 GB for 10K threads. You should set the default stack size to some value between 64k and 512k, which isn't a problem, because most applications don't require deeper call stacks.
- If the connections are short-lived, optimize for new connections by creating several sockets on the same endpoint with the option `SO_REUSEPORT`.
- Increase the user limits: `open files` (default 1.024), `max user processes`
- Increase system limits, e.g. `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` (default 32K), `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`, and `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count` (default 65K).

The application mentioned above was initially designed to handle only 2K concurrent connections. However, with the growth in use, we didn't have to make significant changes to the code in order to scale up to 50K connections.

Comment: This is essentially using the thread scheduling system as the packet scheduling system: thread scheduler determines which `read()` to call next depending on which data arrives. It works, obviously, but there are more scalable designs.

Answer (score 24):

You might like a recent follow-up on the subject: [The Secret To 10 Million Concurrent Connections -The Kernel Is The Problem, Not The Solution](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/13/the-secret-to-10-million-concurrent-connections-the-kernel-i.html).

Comment: What an amazing article man!! I think that I can learn a lot from it, thank you :)

Comment: @Str1101 I found it quite instructive too.

Comment: Makes me think of exokernels again.

Answer (score 5):

The usual approaches for servers are either: (a) thread per connection (often with a thread pool), or (b) single threaded with asynchronous IO (often with epoll or kqueue). My thinking is that some elements of these approaches can, and often should, be combined to use asynchronous IO (with epoll or kqueue) and then hand off the connection request to a thread pool to process. This approach would combine the efficient dispatch of asynchronous IO with the parallelism provided by the thread pool.

I have written such a server for fun (in C++) that uses epoll on Linux and kqueue on FreeBSD and OSX along with a thread pool. I just need to run it through its paces for heavy testing, do some code cleanup, and then toss it out on github (hopefully soon).

Comment: Maybe is that I am a little confused, but I thought that `epoll` was not exactly asynchronous. After some research I found several texts saying that `AIO` would work better in combination with a thread pool, and `epoll` with a single thread: [Comparing the aio and epoll](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0305.2/0697.html).

Comment: ...I also have read that there are some difficulties regarding the implementation of `AIO`, so maybe it is still more profitable to use the `epoll` + thread pool approach. [whats-the-difference-between...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844955/whats-the-difference-between-event-driven-and-asynchronous-between-epoll-and-a). My own idea about it is that it would be possible to use directly one thread of the pool to hand off every connection until the number of simultaneous connections comes close to the maximum number of threads that the system can sustain, and then we could use the...

Comment: epoll/kqueue/AIO system to handle the new incoming connections while all the threads are busy. (p.s.: I would really love to see your server soon, especially if it is written in C++ :)

Comment: @Str1101: epoll is asynchronous per-socket, and AIO is asynchronous per-request. I.e. if you can guarantee that each socket is used ONLY in one specific thread (which BTW is a Good Idea(tm) regardless of using epoll for several reasons, cache locality included), you'll be fine with epoll in multi-threaded environment. </beating dead horse>