# Linux poll with a thread pool and multiple events

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, polling

I am working on a simple client server program in C in which multiple clients will be connected to a single server.

Clients will submit operations/actions to the server and the server will process these requests. These operations may be expensive and/or long running so ideally I would like to have a thread pool on the server that can concurrently process requests rather than block the main thread.

In addition I also thought that using `poll` (can't use `epoll` as I need to be POSIX compliant) might be better performance wise rather than creating a new thread per socket connection (stems from the C10K problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).

So in theory the server might look like the following pseudo code

```
int main()
{
  // Pretend these are initialized in some manner
  ThreadPool thread_pool;
  Socket server_listening_socket;
  PolledFileDescriptors list_of_polled_fds;

  // The first pollfd will be the listening socket which looks for read events on it
  list_of_polled_fds[0].fd = server_listening_socket;
  list_of_polled_fds[0].events = POLLIN;

  while (true)
  {
    // Call poll on our list of file descriptors with unlimited timeout (-1)
    poll(&list_of_polled_fds, number_of_fds, -1);
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_fds; i++)
    {
      // We received a read event on this file descriptor
      if (list_of_polled_fds[i].revents & POLLIN)
      {
 
        // The listening socket has an event (meaning a new connection was created) 
        if (i == 0)
        {
          Socket client_socket = accept();
          AddClientConnectionToListOfPollFds(&list_of_polled_fds, client_socket);
        }

        // A connected client has an event (data was sent over the socket)
        else
        {  
          ThreadPoolTask task = {
            .argument = list_of_polled_fds[i].fd // client connected file descriptor
            .function = SomeFunctionToReadDataFromSocketAndProcessIt
          };
          AddTaskToThreadPool(&thread_pool, &task);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now with this high level design I have a few concerns.

#### Single Message Causes Multiple Events

- Suppose the client tries to send the server a message of 10 bytes, but for some reason the bytes get split into 2 TCP packets.
- The first packet will come in on the client socket and this will cause `poll` to detect an event.
- It will then place this socket into a task on the thread pool which will read and process the data.
- The second packet then comes in and causes poll to do the same thing.
- Now I have 2 tasks in my thread pool that correspond to the same socket and for what should be the same "message".

How should I manage this? Should I just keep track of which sockets are currently being worked on in the thread pool and not add the same socket if a task exists?

If I guard the thread pool from adding the same socket twice, then that means if a single client sends 2 independent requests, I will not be able to process them in parallel. I will have to wait for the first message to finish and then process the next one.

What is a good mechanism for detecting if multiple `poll` events belong so a single client message so I can both not add redundant tasks to my thread pool, but still process multiple requests from the client simultaneously?

Comment: Assign one thread for each event source (fd), not for each event.

Comment: @dimich What about in the large case scenario where there are 10,000 or more connections? It sounds like I'll need 10,000 threads open at the same time which will probably yield some performance problems.

Comment: How it differs from acquiring one thread per event? Number of threads is limited by your pool capacity. You should use non-blocking sockets and put descriptor to poll list only if `recv()` returned `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`. epoll is more convenient mechanism for such scenario.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593699/tcp-ip-solving-the-c10k-with-the-thread-per-client-approach <- C10k @ 1 thread per connection on Linux reported as feasible 10 years ago

Comment: @dimich Oh that is an interesting approach. So part of my data framing is that I send 4 bytes which represent the upcoming message size in bytes. Then I just receive 4 byte to get that size. 

Are you suggesting that in the main thread I set the sockets as non blocking and try to recv all the data for a single "message" and only if I can receive the full message I place it into my thread pool?

If I can not receive the full message (I.E. `recv` sets the error to `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`, then I place the file descriptor into the poll list and try again to receive the full message?

Comment: @teapot418
Wow, somehow I did not see that post. I guess it is pretty feasible for every incoming connection (socket) to get its own software thread. Perhaps I don't even need a thread pool, or at least a heavy duty one like I have.

Comment: You may need a _process_ pool rather than a _thread_ pool because the file descriptor limit is 1024 for each process but threads _share_ that value. Or, a two level pool approach: for 10,000 connections we need 10 processes that have 1000 threads each.

Comment: @CraigEstey 1024 descriptors per-process is a default limit value and can be increased.

Comment: @nick2225 You can have per-connection buffer associated with descriptor. Besides received data buffer contains size of this data. Worker thread appends data to a buffer and invokes handler when entire message is received, or "returns" to a pool if no data available yet (read attempt returned EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK).

Comment: TCP takes care of segmentation and reassembly so you only get complete messages.

Comment: @stark umm.. only for 'messages' of one byte.